# Passing a function that returns an object in Dart / Flutter does not work

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, dart

I'm pretty new in Dart coding world.

I'm using Sembast (ver 2.1.1) and coding in Flutter. 
I've created an abstract class called ImageItem. Then other types of images inherit from it, say a ArtworkItem class:

```
class ArtworkItem extends ImageItem {

    DateTime lastUpdated;
    String category;

    ArtworkItem({
       this.lastUpdated,
       this.category,
    );

    static ArtworkItem fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
       return ArtworkItem(
          lastUpdated = map['last_updated'],
          category = map['category'], 
       );       
    }
}
```

So in the code above the ArtworkItem has a static method that returns the ArtworkItem object from a map.
Then there is a class called Repository. Repository has a method that has takes a Function as a parameter, and it returns a List. Like this:

```
List<ImageItem> getImagesFromRepository(ImageItem Function(Map<String, dynamic) fromMap) {

   // Do something here to get List of RecordSnapshot object.
   // ....Additional code here
   final recordSnapshots = await _store.find( await database, finder: finder, );

   return recordSnapshot.map((snapshot) => fromMap(snapshot.value));

}
```

And when I call this method like this in a DAO file:

```
return getImagesFromRepository(ArtworkItem.fromMap);
```

I got and Exception: 
`'MappedListIterable<SembastRecordSnapshot<String, Map<String, dynamic>>, ImageItem>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ImageItem>'`

But if I do:

```
return recordSnapshots
    .map(
        (snapshot) => ArtworkItem.fromMap(snapshot.value))
    .toList();
```

This works, just by specifying explicitly ArtworkItem.fromMap it works. But this will defeat the purpose of abstraction.

Comment: Do you get any error? Also, what is recordSnapshot?

Comment: RecordSnapshot is a type in Sembast package. it holds Map<dynamic, dynamic>. More info go to: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/sembast

Comment: And there was no error, just stalled.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just make a wild guess that your callback isn't explicitly typed.

```dart
List<ImageItem> getImagesFromRepository(ImageItem Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromMap) {}
```

Comment: I have tried but it still does not work.. still the same, it stalled.. thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: @zk_regen The code you attached doesn't look so bad, at least it should give runtime errors if there's type mismatch, but it shouldn't just stuck. Are you sure you don't have some kind of infinite loop while working with DB? Can you show more code how you work with DB?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I got an exception after I did it in try catch block. I have updated the question above to include the exception. Thanks again.

Comment: @zk_regen This exception message looks like you're missing `.toList()` after `.map(...)`. Do you still have it before returning from `getImagesFromRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is not a supported type in sembast (it uses json which does not support DateTime). `lastUpdated` should/could be converted to an int (millis since epoch) or an ISO8601 string.

I don't if that's the reason of your issue (I'm assuming recordSnapshot is of type List, not RecordSnapshot) and why you did not get any error before. It is hard to say whether your app is stalled as you said or whether an exception was thrown, you could try to wrap into a try/catch and print the error for debugging purpose.

Comment: Thanks for answering. recordSnapshots is a List<RecordSnapshot<dynamic, dynamic>>. It was obtained from: 
`
final recordSnapshots = await _store.find(
      await database,
      finder: finder,
    );
`

And the fromMap method already took care of the Timestamp to int conversion using its seconds property.

So after doing try catch block I got this exception:
type 'MappedListIterable<SembastRecordSnapshot<String, Map<String, dynamic>>, ImageItem>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ImageItem>'

I have updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

@zk_regen, i think your `getImagesFromRepository` function is expecting incorrect parameter. I think it should expect `ImageItem` if you're passing an instance of `ArtworkItem` like so,

```
List<ImageItem> getImagesFromRepository(ImageItem imageItem) {

   // Do something here to get List of RecordSnapshot object.
```